# installation java error

Tags: java, error-handling

when i trying to install java in my ubuntu 14.04 os from

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

error shows

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-sql-sqlite:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how to resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install this package before `libqt4-sql-sqlite`?

It looks like you tried to install it before and it wasn't installed correctly.

This doesn't mean that java was not installed try executing `java --version` on your machine it must work.

To delete this problem try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` this must remove unconfigured and broken packages from your system.

Comment: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
when i try apt-get autoremove

Comment: Did you try if java is working?

Comment: It appears that `libqt4-sql-sqlite` is installed but not configured try to configure it with `dpkg --configure -a`.